# Mean value of grouped bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a bar plot and add a mean line to each group. As the values are negative, I reversed the Y-axis. The bar plot is represented successfully with the reversed Y-axis.

Then I added the mean line of each group (type). Unfortunately the mean line is not draw in the reversed Y-axis. The **mean line** has the wrong sign, it is positive, but should be negative.

Can someone help me and shift the mean line to the upper half of the Y-axis, to the bar plot?

[image: See image of current bar plot with mean value]

This is the used code so far:

```
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Type,y=Value, fill=Iteration))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "errorbar", 
               aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y.., group = Type),
               width = 1, linetype = "solid", color = "red")+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add - in front like this way:

```
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Type,y=Value, fill=Iteration))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "errorbar", 
               aes(ymax = - ..y.., ymin = - ..y.., group = Type),
               width = 1, linetype = "solid", color = "red")+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")
```